# How to change size of menu text and icons in Microsoft Office

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

Microsoft Office windows don't look like other application windows.  Everything is "bigger": the text font in menus and the ribbon, the vertical width of the window title and menu bar, etc.  It got worse a month or so ago when the IT department pushed an Office update.  There is just a lot of wasted space, esp. when using the laptop monitor and not my external one.

I am *not* asking a question about the size of text or other things in Windows, but Office apps in particular.  If I could make Office windows look like "normal windows" I'd be happy.  No, changing the Office theme to "system settings" doesn't help.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Did you check the resolution in Windows?